# The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentTransaction, String)

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with Fragments.

Problem what i am facing is, i have a simple `DialogFragment`

```
public class Fragment3 extends DialogFragment  {
private Fragment activity;
ViewGroup root;

static Fragment3 newInstance() {
    Fragment3 f = new Fragment3();
    return f;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3_layout, container, false);
    return root;
  } 
}
```

And i want to create this Fragment from another Fragment

```
public class ListViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Fragment activity;
....

public ListViewImageAdapter(Fragment activity, ArrayList<Object> listImages) {
    this.activity = activity;
 ...}

....
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment3 newFragment = Fragment3.newInstance();
newFragment.show( ft, "dialog");
....
```

But I get a message:

```
The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentTransaction, String)
```

Comment: you are probably mixing the import, part could be from the support library part from the framework

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

instead of:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

(or the reverse)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `newFragment.show( activity.getFragmentManager(), "dialog");` instead of `newFragment.show( ft, "dialog");` . DialogFragment.show() method takes `FragmentManager` as first argument, not `FragmentTransaction`. Please take a look on [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)